Mui v5: How to make a grid item to use the 100% of the available dialog's height
I am unable to set the height of a Grid Item to occupy all the available height of a MUI's dialog content space.
In the photo below I want Left Side Panel, Main and Right Panel to extend to the end of the dialog space "orange color"

Here is my codesandbox code.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dialog-with-grid-nx5kkc?file=%2Fdemo.js%3A71%2C78
EDIT: I changed the layout to this below but when I set an xs value for the 2nd or 3rd part do not seem to work.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dialog-with-grid-new-xhrm69?file=%2Fdemo.js%3A75%2C36
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function ConfirmationDialogRaw(props) {
  const { onClose, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Dialog
      maxWidth="96%"
      PaperProps={{
        sx: {
          width: "96%",
          height: "100%",
        },
      }}
      onClose={onClose}
      {...other}
    >
      <DialogContent>
        <Container sx={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <Box sx={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <Grid container direction="row" spacing={2} sx={{ height: "100%" }}>
              {/* ------------------------ */}

              <Grid item xs={10}>
                <Grid
                  container
                  direction="column"
                  sx={{ p: 0, height: "100%" }}
                  xs
                >
                  {/* ----- */}
                  <Grid item sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
                    <Stack
                      sx={{
                        height: "80px",
                        border: "1px solid black",
                        fontSize: 30,
                        textAlign: "center",
                      }}
                    >
                      1
                    </Stack>
                  </Grid>
                  {/* ----- */}
                  <Grid xs item sx={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: "100%" }}>
                    <Grid
                      container
                      direction="row"
                      spacing={0}
                      sx={{ height: "100%" }}
                      xs
                    >
                      <Grid item xs>
                        <Stack
                          sx={{
                            height: "100%",
                            border: "1px solid black",
                            fontSize: 30,
                            textAlign: "center",
                          }}
                        >
                          2
                        </Stack>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs>
                        <Stack
                          sx={{
                            height: "100%",
                            border: "1px solid black",
                            fontSize: 30,
                            textAlign: "center",
                          }}
                        >
                          3
                        </Stack>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              {/* --------------------- */}

              <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Stack
                  sx={{
                    height: "100%",
                    minHeight: 150,
                    border: "1px solid black",
                    fontSize: 30,
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  4
                </Stack>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={onClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={onClose}>Ok</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default function Demo() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
        Open dialog
      </Button>
      <ConfirmationDialogRaw
        id="ringtone-menu"
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      />
    </>
  );
}


For your Container use
<Container sx={{ height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#f3a432", px: 0 }}>.
The Mui Container has a default padding applied to it.
